# Using Two inputviews for same UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I am having a UITextField which can input date using a data picker and as well as with numeric keyboard, When user taps directly to UITextField numeric keyboard should open but when user taps on UIButton DatePicker Should open.

My Code :

```
userInfo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditing), for: .editingDidBegin)
func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
         sender.inputView = nil
         sender.inputAccessoryView = nil
         sender.reloadInputViews()
}
func pickUpDate(){

        // DatePicker
        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        datePicker.setValue(Constants.Colors.AppGreen, forKey: "textColor")
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
        let currentDate: Date = Date()
        let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()


        if txtFDOB.textFieldType == UserBasicDetailCellType.UserBasicDetailCellDOBType {
            components.year = -18
            let minDate: Date = gregorian.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))!

            components.year = -150
            let maxDate: Date = gregorian.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))!
            datePicker.maximumDate = minDate
            datePicker.minimumDate = maxDate

            datePicker.date = minDate
        }
        if txtFDOB.textFieldType == UserBasicDetailCellType.UserBasicDetailCellNomineeDOBType {
            components.year = -18
            let minDate: Date = gregorian.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))!
            datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
            datePicker.maximumDate = currentDate
        }

        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = Constants.Colors.DarkGrey
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Adding Button ToolBar
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(KycFormViewController.doneClick))
        doneButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : Constants.Colors.AppGreen,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:Constants.Colors.LightGrey],for: UIControlState.normal)

        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(KycFormViewController.cancelClick))
        cancelButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : Constants.Colors.AppGreen,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.black],
                                            for: UIControlState.normal)
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        txtFDOB.resignFirstResponder()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.txtFDOB.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            self.txtFDOB.inputView = self.datePicker
            self.txtFDOB.becomeFirstResponder()
        }        
    }
```

Now When I resignFirstResponder() and make FirstResponder again textFieldEditing get called and set InputViews to nil.

Any other way to implement the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this one not clear can you elobate `ow When I resignFirstResponder() and make FirstResponder again textFieldEditing get called and set InputViews to nil.`

Comment: When DatePicker method call in the end I do this txtFDOB.resignFirstResponder()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.txtFDOB.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            self.txtFDOB.inputView = self.datePicker
            self.txtFDOB.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
After Which my textFeildEditing Method get called which sets inputview to nil

Comment: what the purpose u don this

Comment: To resign number keyboard and get datepicker as inputView

Comment: I partially Understand when first proecess is over you want to show date picker again as input view, correct

Comment: use case is when number keyboard is already visible and users tap button input date using datepicker, now I want to resign the existing keyboard and show datepicker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135654/discussion-between-haroon-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: show the button action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

**step-1**

remove the following code inside the methof  `func pickUpDate()`

```
txtFDOB.resignFirstResponder()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.txtFDOB.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        self.txtFDOB.inputView = self.datePicker
        self.txtFDOB.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

**step-2**

```
call/Move your `func pickUpDate()` to `viewdidload`
```

**step-3**

your textfield `func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField)` is correct, same like do in your button also, like this

```
 func datePickerClicked(sender: UIButton!) { 
txtFDOB.resignFirstResponder() 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { 
self.txtFDOB.inputAccessoryView = toolBar 
self.txtFDOB.inputView = self.datePicker 
self.txtFDOB.becomeFirstResponder() 
} 
}
```